# Переадресация портов

Tags: порты, linux

Дано:3 девайса1 - шлюз на линуксе (192.168.1.10)2 - ПК с поднятым прокси сервером (192.168.1.117) (имеет другой шлюз)3 - телефон (192.168.1.15)

Linux поднят на виртуалке на том же пк что и винда (п2)Задача.в устройстве 3 шлюзом указан шлюз 1 (192.168.1.10), необходимо что бы запросы, которые приходят с 3го (192.168.1.15) устройства на шлюз по портам 80,443 перенаправлялись на проксb сервер (192.168.1.117:8888) затем ответ уходил обратно на 3 устр (192.168.1.15)

в Лин я полный нуб. На сколько я понял реализуется при помощи iptables. Перерыл выдачу гугла и яндекса, однако ничего не помогло.Подскажите что делать и как быть?

Comment: Честно сказать делал много раз перенаправления в дебике, но по такому ТЗ ничего не понятно...Опишите нормально...

Comment: я бы сказал - нарисуйте

Answer (score 1):

как я понял из описанного есть 3 тачки (виртуальностью в данной схеме можно пренебречь).

```
inet  inet  |     |  2  -  1  -  3proxy  nat   comp
```

на 2(proxy) видимо нестроен transparent, поэтому можно использовать любой хауту, например [этот](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html)

**--dport 80** - это ваш 80.. 443 работать не будет в прозрачном режиме и его нужно отпроксировать конкретно (т.е. указав в клиентских программах)

**squid-box:3128** - нужно заменить на 192.168.1.117:8888